# How to parse multiline java ERROR/Exception stack traces input in fluentd (I should see the same ERROR/Exception stacktrace through Kibana)

Tags: java, multiline, fluentd

I am using EFK.

Could someone help here on how to parse multiline java stack traces through fluentd in order to push the whole stacktrace in log message field (I should see the same ERROR/Exception stacktrace through Kibana).

### I need to parse the following error stack trace:

```
2019-06-10 16:51:48.789  INFO 11360 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6293 ms
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2019-06-10 16:51:52.633 ERROR 11360 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'ec2-13-233-117-154.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
```

---

### My fluent.conf file configuration is as follows:

```
# fluentd/conf/fluent.conf
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
  <parse>
    @type multiline
    format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/
    format /(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<path>[^ ]*) (?<method>[^ ]*) (?<message>[^ ](.*?(\n)).*$)/
  </parse>
</source>

<match **>
  #@type copy
  @type detect_exceptions
  <store>
   @type elasticsearch
   host elasticsearch
   port 9200
   logstash_format true
   logstash_prefix fluentd
   logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
   include_tag_key true
   type_name access_log
   tag_key @log_name
   flush_interval 1s
  </store>
</match>
```

---

### Tried with following 3 pluggins, but I didn't get the required input:

```
fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions-with-error-0.0.3
fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions-0.0.12
fluent-plugin-concat-2.4.0
```

---

### When I used the above configuration I am getting the following ERROR into fluentd container logs:

```
2019-08-02 12:46:23 +0000 [error]: config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown output plugin 'detect_exceptions'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you installed the plugin.
You can install it with following command

```
gem install fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions
```

I use following config on my agents. Note that I make retag with *fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter* before check if message is the stack trace.

```
<match tag>
  @type                       rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key                       container_id
    pattern                   /(.+)/
    tag                       removeme.${tag}.$1
  </rule>
</match>

<match removeme**>
  @type detect_exceptions
  remove_tag_prefix           removeme
  message                     message
  languages                   java, python
  multiline_flush_interval    1
</match>

<match tag_without_prefix**>
  @type                       elasticsearch
  host                        elasticsearch
  port                        9200
  logstash_format             true
  ...
</match>
```

Or you can use @label parameter from this example: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions/issues/19#issuecomment-406628486